# Remove Additional & in the end whilst generating a query string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am constructing a query string for pandas and appending & at the end of each condition

So, for example if I have condition1, condition2, condition3 my query would be generated as:  "condition1 & condition2 & condition3 &"

I am using json to provide flexibility to the user to specify condition and then read json:

```
    {"scenario": "123-456-222",  
     "query": 
        {
          "key": "field1",
          "value": "condition1"
        },
        {
          "key": "field2",
          "value": "condition2"
        },
        {
          "key": "field3",
          "value": "condition3"
        },
    "data":
```

Next, I use python's final_condition[:-1] to remove the redundant & in the end.

Wondering if there's a better way to organise this code.

```
test_str = "field1=condition1 & field2=condition2 & field3=condition3 &"
print(test_str[:-1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to put the ampersands between the operands:

```
args = ["statement 1", "statement 2",  "statement 3"]
output = " & ".join(args)
print(output)
# statement 1 & statement 2 & statement 3
```